# XSD restrictions based on open/closed elements

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way in a schema to indicate the requirement of attributes determined by the open or closed nature of the element. For example i have an element that if open has no requirement for the attribute 'test', however if its closed it is required.

```
<element name="employee" >
    blah!
</element>
```

Ok

```
<element name="employee" />
```

Fail - attribute 'test' required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using "open" to mean that the element has a text node child, and "closed" to mean that it hasn't. So you're saying the element should either have a text node child or an attribute but not both (?) and not neither.

That's classified as a co-occurrence constraint, and can't be done in XSD 1.0. It can be done with assertions in XSD 1.1

```
<xs:element name="employee" type="...">
  <xs:assert test="string(.) or @name"/>
</xs:element>
```

XSD 1.1 support is currently available in Xerces and Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do that.
(I'd cite a reference, but it's hard to reference a non-feature!)

In general, this is a step beyond what XSD provides; in only a very few cases (like IDREFs) does it provide any way to validate one datum by referencing another.  XSD 1.1 provides some new [assertion support](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) that might do what you need, but the spec is just a working draft at this point.